# JSON parsing in PHP of Twitter Stream

Tags: php, json, twitter

i'm playing with the Twitter API, but I can't parse the results given.

This is my PHP code:

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40". $hashtag .               "&count=" . $notweets);


$new = json_encode($tweets);
echo $new;


foreach($new['statuses'] as $item) {
    echo $item['text'];
}
```

and the answer is:

```
{
statuses: [
{
metadata: {
iso_language_code: "ar",
result_type: "recent"
},
created_at: "Fri Dec 12 17:34:40 +0000 2014",
id: 543458929817030000,
id_str: "543458929817030657",
text: "RT @FCOArabic: RT @ukhelps: فيديو: اختراع بريطاني يساعد أطفال #سورية اللاجئين لتعلم مهارات الكمبيوتر @raspberrypi #UKHELPS http://t.co/qpCc…",
source: "Twitter for iPhone</a>",
truncated: false,
in_reply_to_status_id: null,
in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
in_reply_to_user_id: null,
in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,
in_reply_to_screen_name: null,
user: {
id: 2903018041,
id_str: "2903018041",
name: "hiba ahmad",
screen_name: "hibaahm98349727",
location: "",
profile_location: null,
description: "",
url: null,
entities: {
description: {
urls: [ ]
}
},
protected: false,
followers_count: 4,
friends_count: 19,
listed_count: 0,
created_at: "Mon Nov 17 18:46:27 +0000 2014",
favourites_count: 3,
utc_offset: null,
time_zone: null,
geo_enabled: false,
verified: false,
statuses_count: 36,
lang: "ar",
contributors_enabled: false,
is_translator: false,
is_translation_enabled: false,
profile_background_color: "C0DEED",
profile_background_image_url: "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
profile_background_image_url_https: "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
profile_background_tile: false,
profile_image_url: "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/543090320179601408/e5DYdo_Q_normal.jpeg",
profile_image_url_https: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/543090320179601408/e5DYdo_Q_normal.jpeg",
profile_banner_url: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2903018041/1418318037",
profile_link_color: "0084B4",
profile_sidebar_border_color: "C0DEED",
profile_sidebar_fill_color: "DDEEF6",
profile_text_color: "333333",
profile_use_background_image: true,
default_profile: true,
default_profile_image: false,
following: false,
follow_request_sent: false,
notifications: false
},
geo: null,
coordinates: null,
place: null,
contributors: null,
retweeted_status: {
metadata: {
iso_language_code: "ar",
result_type: "recent"
},
created_at: "Thu Dec 11 22:05:16 +0000 2014",
id: 543164639811740000,
id_str: "543164639811735552",
text: "RT @ukhelps: فيديو: اختراع بريطاني يساعد أطفال #سورية اللاجئين لتعلم مهارات الكمبيوتر @raspberrypi #UKHELPS http://t.co/qpCcHYXpup",
source: "Hootsuite</a>",
truncated: false,
in_reply_to_status_id: null,
in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
in_reply_to_user_id: null,
in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,
in_reply_to_screen_name: null,
}
```

It asks for the hashtag #raspberrypi and I get this answer which I encoded with `json_encode();`

How do I parse this correctly? I only want to get the text of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `$connection->get()` method returns, but if its a JSON-string you should use json_decode instead of json_encode.

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40". $hashtag .               "&count=" . $notweets);

$tweetsArray = json_decode($tweets, true);
foreach($tweetsArray['statuses'] as $item) {
    echo $item['text'];
}
```